# Access - Error 3615 when joining two decimals

Tags: ms-access

I've got two tables.
The first one looks like this. The type of the numbers is decimal.

```
TABLE1
T1NUMBER  T1INFORMATION
123456    Stuff1
123457    Stuff2
123458    Stuff3
```

My other table looks similar. Basically the id is the same as in the other table, but with two extra characters at the end.

```
TABLE2
T2NUMBER    T2INFORMATION
123456L1    Important Info1
123457L1    Important Info2
123458L1    Important Info3
```

To join the tables, I made a query to cut the extra characters.  I know, that I can only match decimal colums with decimal ones. So I added a function, that converts the string I got to a decimal. The result of the query looks like this.

```
QUERY1
Q1NUMBER  Q1INFORMATION
123456    Important Info1
123457    Important Info2
123458    Important Info3
```

The function I used to get a decimal value is this one. I added it as a module.

```
Function NewCDec(MyVal)
   NewCDec = CDec(MyVal)
End Function
```

Let's finally get to my problem. I want to join TABLE1 with QUERY1 on the numerical columns. Both should now be decimal values and should be joinable. But I always get error 3615 (Type mismatch in JOIN expression). Why do I still get that error? Can anyone help me fix it?

My query should look like this in the end:

```
RESULT
NUMBER    T1INFORMATION  Q1INFORMATION
123456    Stuff1         Important Info1
123457    Stuff2         Important Info2
123458    Stuff3         Important Info3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error. Some values at T2NUMBER where invalid/null and I forget to filter that. So Access didn't let me join the tables. It worked after I filtered the null values.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, a simple change in your function should solve the problem.

```
Function NewCDec(ByVal MyVal As String) As Double
   NewCDec = CDec(MyVal)
End Function
```

From the information provided in your question, this should solve the problem.

But when it comes to problems, logics sometime doesn't work!!

So, if the above changes doesn't work. Try to put your `CDec()` in SQL by creating a temporary table using `(SELECT ... FROM Table) As TempTable`.

**SIMPLE EXAMPLE:**

```
SELECT CDec(T2NUMBER) As Number FROM Table2
```

**TEMP TABLE EXAMPLE:**

```
SELECT TempTable.* FROM (SELECT CDec(T2NUMBER) As Number FROM Table2) As TempTable
```